# Can't draw anything on my JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, preferredsize

Just trying to understand simple Java things. Cant'get this thing to work. Warning : lots of bad code incoming.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;


class DrawFrame  {
    public DrawFrame(){
        DrawPanels panelFrame=new DrawPanels();
        JFrame mainFrame=new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setSize(480, 800);
        mainFrame.setTitle("Title");
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.add(panelFrame.panel1);
        mainFrame.add(panelFrame.panel2);
        mainFrame.add(panelFrame.panel3);
        //panelFrame.panel1.getGraphics();
        panelFrame.panel1.add(new DrawBlock());
        panelFrame.panel2.add(new DrawBlock());
        panelFrame.panel3.add(new DrawBlock());
        mainFrame.revalidate();
        mainFrame.repaint();
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    }
class DrawPanels extends JPanel{
     JPanel panel1=new JPanel();
     JPanel panel2=new JPanel();
     JPanel panel3=new JPanel();
    public DrawPanels(){
        panel1.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panel1.setVisible(true);
        panel2.setVisible(true);
        panel3.setVisible(true);
        panel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    }
}

class DrawBlock extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(1, 1,15,15);
    }
}


public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        DrawFrame Windos=new DrawFrame();
    }}
```

If my class DrawBlock extends JPanel, there will be a small white square at each JPanel, however, there is no reaction for paintComponent() method. If i extend DrawBlock to JComponent, there will be no squares at all. This is probably beginners problem, but i can't resolve it.

Comment: Have you set the color to anything other than white?

Comment: Just tried gray color, didn't help me. Still small white square.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/). See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue you have is the fact that `DrawBlock` actually has no size, therefore, the repaint manager automatically discards painting it...

[image]

Try modifying you code as such...

```
public class DrawBlock extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(18, 18);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("...");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(1, 1, 15, 15);
    }
}
```

Adding the `getPreferredSize` method will let the layout manager know what size your component would like to be...

### Warning - Code Review ;)

I'm not sure why you've done what you've done, but lets leave that aside...

You create a class that extends from `JPanel` (`DrawPanels`) that contains a number of other `JPanel`s, but instead of adding them to the frame, you extract the panels from it and those to the frame...

It would make more sense to simply add the `DrawPanels` directly to the frame itself...

```
public static class DrawFrame {

    public DrawFrame() {
        DrawPanels panelFrame = new DrawPanels();
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.setSize(480, 800);
        mainFrame.setTitle("Title");
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.add(panelFrame);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class DrawPanels extends JPanel {

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

    public DrawPanels() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        panel1.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel3.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        panel1.add(new DrawBlock());
        panel2.add(new DrawBlock());
        panel3.add(new DrawBlock());

        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);
        add(panel3);

    }
}
```

Note - I moved the `mainFrame.setVisible(true)` to the last statement, this will ensure that the frame is laid out before it is made visible.

I also moved the layout managers around a bit...

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question and for Code Review. Too bad i can't get + rep.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:***
Try to remove the

```
mainFrame.revalidate();
```

That's not a recognized command for `JFrame`.

Furthermore add @Override Annotation to your paintComponent:

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(1, 1,15,15);
    }
```

Then it works best for me.

Comment: Tried this before asking my question, tried it now. Still i got this http://gyazo.com/2db02444bbe2edc3089f7c6dd969673d

Comment: Deleting this method didn't make a change, but anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use `g.setColor(Color.WHITE)` before `g.drawRect(1, 1,15,15);`